# JSON Response to object and C# Best Practice?

Tags: c#, json, api

I am using an API to make requests to to a process.

The response from the server is not always exactly the same size or dimension to compare it to an array.

Response look like this in json...

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "ResponseHeader": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "RequestID": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Status": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "severity": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "statusDesc": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "sStatusCode": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "statusCode": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "AStatus": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "statusCode": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "serverStatusCode": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "severity": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "statusDesc": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "contact": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "acNumber": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "floatName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "pData": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "fullName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "familyName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "iIdent": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "number": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "description": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "verificationResults": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "emp": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "properties": {
                            "employer": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Income": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Title": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "empId": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "miscData": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "properties": [],
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "pAddress": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "properties": {
                            "addType": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "add1": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "add2": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "city": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "zipCode": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What is the best practice / correct way to create this as an object in C#?**

Do I create a class?
Do I create it as an array?

I know that I have seen a few questions with answers related to this but none of them talk about best practice.

Comment: There are pre-built tools for this.  Look for open source JSON, I cant remember the one I used but it made it very easy to create an object with properties from the return data as you show in your example.

Comment: Thank you Joe, I have been searching and I am guessing a class is the best practice.  Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing that comes to mind is using visual studio's paste special ability. That creates a class based off of a piece of Json or XML that you have in your clipboard.

[image]

Comment: Hello Asharif, I never used this feature.  I am guessing that is pointing me at using the class as the best practice.  I will mark this as answered unless I find a better article or something later.  Thank you